# Is it "Does social media" or "Do social media"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I am confused as to which way to say the following:

"Does social media benefit people?"

or

"Do social media benefit people?"

Comment: I would go for the first one, but I don't think the second one is incorrect.

Comment: It's almost certainly been covered here before, but [Grammar-Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/agenda_data_criteria_singular_or_plural.htm) explains what's going on.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Grammar-Monster is over-hasty in declaring "data are" to be "outdated." See [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=data+is%2Cdata+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3): "data are" continues to edge out "data is" in frequency.

Comment: @Brian Donovan There is an argument for choosing plural count-noun or mass-noun usage on merit. However, both a raw Google search (3 : 1 in favour of 'data is') and The American Heritage® Dictionary of Student Science, Second Edition. Copyright © 2014 by Houghton Mifflin ('Usage: In scientific writing, data is usually treated as a singular in much the same way as the word information is.... But because the word is historically the plural of the Latin noun datum, it is sometimes used as a plural ... The plural use is less frequent than the singular.') are at odds with the Ngram results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purists will insist that *media* be treated as a plural (the plural of *medium),* but the tribunal of use has long authorized its use as a mass noun. Both usages are established, then: see [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=media%20is%2C%20media%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

(Frankly, what puzzles me more is how *social* can modify *medium/media*—for how can a communications medium *not* be social?)

Comment: I can't see anything particularly "social" about a [growing medium](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+growing+medium%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (artificial soil, etc.). And that one [pluralises to **media**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22used+growing+media%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) just the same. I can imagine "**antisocial** growing medium" being used to describe a product that smells like horseshit, so maybe a social medium might be one that *doesn't* smell bad! :)

Comment: +1 But a computer communicates with a milling machine using media that is social only in that it exists within a society.